# What do the braces mean in the following function definition?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

What do the braces mean in the following function definition?

```
(state, { copy }) => state.push(createItem(copy));
```

Comment: ..sure that is valid code?

Comment: @Reeno That question is about curly braces in the call of the function, not in the definition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In ES6, this is known as [Object Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring).

In that particular aspect, it means I can pass an object in as a parameter of a function and it gets *transformed* into variables that I can access within that function, for example:

```
function f(param1, { param2, param3 }) {
  console.log(param2, param3)
}
f("one", {
  param2: "A",
  param3: "B"
});
```

[Babel REPL Example](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=function%20f(param1%2C%20%7B%20param2%2C%20param3%20%7D)%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log(param2%2C%20param3)%0A%7D%0Af(%22one%22%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20param2%3A%20%22A%22%2C%0A%20%20param3%3A%20%22B%22%0A%7D)%3B)

The advantage being that instead of calling:

```
f("one", myObject.one, myObject.two);
```

I can simply call:

```
f("one", myObject);
```

And the `one`, `two` parameters will be mapped for me accordingly.

Comment: @zerkms Very good point, I'll remove that statement